# How to update container states when running on cloud run?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-run

I have a large pool of containers serving high load of web traffic, they need to store a relatively small amount of data in memory to serve these requests.

The creation and update of the objects these containers are storing happens on another service, when that service creates a new object which is stored in PG, I need all the containers serving the data to be updated to this new state.

My current implementation listens to the updates on postgres directly, but this means those services are coupled to the database of another service and this feels like an anti-pattern.

So my question is what are the approaches I could use to update all of my cloud run containers when new data arrives in the source of truth?

Comment: Cloud Run is primarily stateless but can be integrated with stateful services such as Cloud SQL, Secrets Manager, Cloud Storage, etc. Requiring state is an antipattern as you would say. Since Cloud Run instances can stop or start at any time in response to traffic requirements, listening to events from another service (database) can be problematic. Is your architecture the correct one to deploy on Cloud Run or would traditional compute (Compute Engine) be more appropriate?

Comment: It is a fair point, but I am pretty all in on cloud run.
My current plan is to have the services expose an update endpoint, which would write to firebase to which all containers of the service would be subscribed, and therefore they would all be updated. Seems ok... what are you thoughts @JohnHanley ?

Comment: I recommend reading about the Cloud Run life cycle. When an instance is not processing an HTTP request, it receives no CPU time. That means TCP connections will fail and you must embed lots of error handling, retry logic, etc. You can enable always on CPU but then your costs go up. Time and again I see developers trying to use the wrong service for their design. Either change your design to fit the service or change the service to fit your design.

Comment: Sorry @JohnHanley I think you have gone a little far here without grasping the full design. The service will read a FB collection on start up, and store this in memory, this is no different for when developing with a standard cloud VM, where you need to factor the service going down etc. Appreciate the input but would also suggest not to make sweeping "you don't know what your doing statements" on SO.

Comment: Your statement **all containers of the service would be subscribed** is a design concern for Cloud Run. I never said you don't know what you are doing. I said to read about the Cloud Run life cycle so that you know what you can and cannot do (without undue complexity).